# How can I detect if emacs was started with "-Q"?

Tags: emacs, command-line-arguments, startup

I have an Emacs package that needs to save some state when quitting Emacs, but I don't want to save that state if Emacs was run with `-Q`. Is there a way to distinguish when Emacs is run with `-Q` or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test [`command-line-args`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html) (see [`lisp/startup.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/startup.el) for more):

```
(or (member "-Q" command-line-args)
    (member "-quick" command-line-args))
```

You might prefer a "lower-level" approach: instead of checking for the specific command line argument, test for its *effect*.
In your case, something like

```
(when init-file-user
  (save-my-state))
```

(note that this will also disable state saving on `-q` and `-no-init-file`).

Comment: Thanks, the `init-file-user` method is exactly what I was looking for.